# Show list of programs on specific drive (Windows 8.1.1 Pro 64-Bit)

Tags: windows

Is there a way of listing all the programs installed on a drive?
I'm using Windows 8.1.1 Pro 64-bit

Comment: Can't you see a list of programs in Control Panel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Open Control Panel

2) Go to Programs and Features (OR 'Uninstall a program' if viewing in Category Mode)

3) Right click on the place shown in the picture (where the arrow points to) and click MORE.

[image]

4) Now from the list that appears, tick the 'Location' checkbox. Now you can see the list of programs in each partition installed in your system.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, ended up using CCleaner, but will definitely do that next time I need to check